# Installing GD Library on Windows

Tags: windows, gd, haskell-stack

I am trying to install [`gd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gd) as a dependency, however it fails on the C libraries not being installed.

```
Configuring gd-3000.7.3...
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign
libraries:
* Missing (or bad) header file: gd.h
* Missing C libraries: gd, png, jpeg, fontconfig, freetype, expat
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
```

I found pre-built [GD for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gd.htm) however I have no idea where should I install it for it to be registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Stack bundle [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) which provides [pacman package manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman).

First try to update MSYS environment using

```
stack exec -- pacman -Syu
```

GD itself can be installed via

```
stack exec -- pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gd
```

Comment: Thanks [/u/tejon on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellgamedev/comments/4jpthu/windows_sdl2_is_now_almost_painless_via_stack/) for this method.